# Spring XD demo - connected car - Open source?

Tags: spring-xd

Came across this Spring XD demo on connected car - thought it's interesting (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkm2GV57hzY).

Wonder if the source code is OSS, available on github or somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently working on the direction of that project.  While the code there isn't open source, I'd be happy (offline) to discuss any of the technical details of the project.